# Generate ASP.Net Membership password hash in pure T-SQL

Tags: asp.net, t-sql, sql-server-2008, hash, asp.net-membership

I'm attempting to create a pure t-sql representation of the default SHA-1 password hashing in the ASP.Net Membership system. Ideally, what I would get would be this:

```
UserName           Password              GeneratedPassword
cbehrens           34098kw4D+FKJ==       34098kw4D+FKJ==
```

Note: that's bogus base-64 text there. I've got base64_encode and decode functions that round-trip correctly. Here's my attempt, which doesn't work:

```
SELECT UserName, Password, dbo.base64_encode(HASHBYTES('SHA1', dbo.base64_decode(PasswordSalt) +  'test')) As TestPassword FROM aspnet_Users U JOIN aspnet_membership M ON U.UserID = M.UserID
```

I've tried a number of variations on the theme, to no avail. I need to do this in pure T-Sql; involving a console app or something like that will double the work.

So if anyone can supply what precisely the syntax should be to duplicate that password from the ASP.Net membership stuff, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: So just to be clear; the issue is that `Password` and `GeneratedPassword` do not match?

Comment: Yup. I can't figure out the precise T-SQL to reproduce the result of the .net Membership code.

Comment: Nope...and it was wrong anyway. I seem to be having trouble expressing myself today.

Comment: Can you post your encode/decode functions so I can test with them?

Comment: I got them both from here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/Miscellaneous/31520/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you are running 2005 or higher, you can create a CLR (.NET) UDF:

```
[SqlFunction(
  IsDeterministic = true, IsPrecise = true, 
  DataAccess = DataAccessKind.None,
  SystemDataAccess = SystemDataAccessKind.None
)]
public static string EncodePassword(string pass, string salt) {
  byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass);
  byte[] src = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);
  byte[] dst = new byte[src.Length + bytes.Length];
  Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 0, dst, 0, src.Length);
  Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, dst, src.Length, bytes.Length);
  using (SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider()) {
    return Convert.ToBase64String(sha1.ComputeHash(dst));
  }
}
```

you need to include the following namespaces in your class:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
```

the class must be **public**.

build the .dll then run the following (per database you want to call the UDF) SQL statement:

```
sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.EncodePassword', N'FS') IS NOT NULL
  DROP FUNCTION dbo.EncodePassword;    
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.assemblies WHERE name='UDF')
DROP ASSEMBLY UDF

CREATE ASSEMBLY UDF FROM 'FULL_PATH_TO.dll' WITH PERMISSION_SET=SAFE    
GO

CREATE FUNCTION EncodePassword(
  @pass NVARCHAR(4000),
  @salt NVARCHAR(4000)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(4000)
-- return NULL if any input parameter(s) are NULL
WITH RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
AS
EXTERNAL NAME UDF.[NAMESPACE.CLASSNAME].EncodePassword
GO
```

obviously, replace 'NAMESPACE.CLASSNAME' with the namespace (if any) and name of your class. and you might want to mess with the input parameter and return value sizes.

then call the UDF with T-SQL:

```
SELECT UserName,Password
,dbo.EncodePassword('PASSWORD', PasswordSalt) As TestPassword 
FROM aspnet_Users U 
JOIN aspnet_membership M ON U.UserID = M.UserID
```

works for me :)

Comment: It works perfectly. Absolutely outstanding work. Thank you very, very much.

Comment: I meant to post this immediately, but it slipped my mind. To the naked eye, the original and generated hash will appear the same, but the generated hash is right-padded with spaces (to fill out the nvarchar(4000)). The fix is tres simple: SELECT RTRIM(dbo.EncodePassword('PASSWORD', PasswordSalt)...

Comment: my bad. (copy/paste) try and replace the return value - instead of `RETURNS NCHAR(4000)` try `RETURNS NVARCHAR(4000)`. untested, but should work.

Answer (score 12):

I wrote a hashing stored proc by reverse enginering the C# code from here [ASP.NET Identity default Password Hasher, how does it work and is it secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20621950/asp-net-identity-default-password-hasher-how-does-it-work-and-is-it-secure) and some fantastic PBKDF2 SQL functions from here [Is there a SQL implementation of PBKDF2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837547/is-there-a-sql-implementation-of-pbkdf2)

First create these two functions taken from [Is there a SQL implementation of PBKDF2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837547/is-there-a-sql-implementation-of-pbkdf2)

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_HMAC]
(
        @hash_algorithm varchar(25),
        @key VARCHAR(MAX),
        @message VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)


AS
BEGIN
    --HASH key if longer than 16 characters
    IF(LEN(@key) >64)
        SET @key = HASHBYTES(@hash_algorithm,@key)


    DECLARE @i_key_pad VARCHAR(MAX), @o_key_pad VARCHAR(MAX), @position INT
        SET @position = 1
        SET @i_key_pad = ''
        SET @o_key_pad = ''

    --splice ipad & opod with key
    WHILE @position <= LEN(@key)
       BEGIN
        SET @i_key_pad = @i_key_pad + CHAR(ASCII(SUBSTRING(@key, @position, 1)) ^ 54) 
        SET @o_key_pad = @o_key_pad + CHAR(ASCII(SUBSTRING(@key, @position, 1)) ^ 92) 
        SET @position = @position + 1
       END 

    --pad i_key_pad & o_key_pad
        SET @i_key_pad = LEFT(@i_key_pad + REPLICATE('6',64),64)
        SET @o_key_pad = LEFT(@o_key_pad + REPLICATE('\',64),64)


RETURN HASHBYTES(@hash_algorithm,CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),@o_key_pad) + HASHBYTES(@hash_algorithm,@i_key_pad + @message))

END

GO
```

and

```
CREATE function [dbo].[fn_PBKDF2] 
(
@hash_algorithm varchar(25),
@password varchar(max),
@salt varchar(max),
@rounds int,
@outputbytes int
)
returns varchar(max)
as
begin

declare @hlen int
select @hlen = len(HASHBYTES(@hash_algorithm, 'test'))
declare @l int 
SET @l = (@outputbytes +@hLen -1)/@hLen
declare @r int 
SET @r = @outputbytes - (@l - 1) * @hLen
declare @t varchar(max), @u varchar(max), @block1 varchar(max)

declare @output varchar(max) 
SET @output = ''

declare @i int 
SET @i = 1
while @i <= @l
    begin
    set @block1 = @salt +cast(cast(@i as varbinary(4)) as varchar(4))
    set @u = dbo.fn_HMAC(@hash_algorithm,@password,@block1)
    set @t = @u

    declare @j int 
    SET @j = 1
    while @j < @rounds
        begin
        set @u = dbo.fn_HMAC(@hash_algorithm,@password,@u)


        declare @k int 
        SET @k = 0 
        DECLARE @workstring varchar(max) 
        SET @workstring = ''
        while @k < @hLen
            begin
            set @workstring = @workstring + char(ascii(substring(@u,@k+1,1))^ascii(substring(@t,@k+1,1)))
            set @k = @k + 1
            end
        set @t = @workstring
        set @j = @j + 1
        end

        select @output = @output + case when @i = @l then left(@t,@r) else @t end
    set @i = @i + 1
    end

  return master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(convert(varbinary(max), @output ))


end
GO
```

then create the stored proc to generate the hash password

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[EncryptPassword2]
    @passwordIn AS VARCHAR(MAX),
    @passwordOut VARCHAR(max) OUTPUT
AS

        -- Generate 16 byte salt
    DECLARE @saltVarBin VARBINARY(max)
    SET @saltVarBin = (SELECT CAST(newid() AS binary(16)))

    -- Base64 encode the salt
    DECLARE @saltOut VARCHAR(max)
    SET @saltOut = cast('' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@saltVarBin"))', 'varchar(max)')

    -- Decode salt to pass to function fn_PBKDF2
    DECLARE @decodedsalt varchar(max)
    SET @decodedsalt = convert(varchar(max),(SELECT CAST('' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@saltOut"))', 'varbinary(max)')))

    -- Build the password binary string from 00 + salt binary string + password binary string created by 32 byte 1000 iteration ORC_PBKDF2 hashing
    DECLARE @passwordVarBinStr VARCHAR(max)
    -- Identity V1.0 and V2.0 Format: { 0x00, salt, subkey } 
    SET @passwordVarBinStr = '0x00' + REPLACE(master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(@saltVarBin) + (SELECT dbo.fn_PBKDF2('sha1', @passwordIn, @decodedsalt, 1000, 32)),'0x','')
    -- Identity V3.0 Format: { 0x01, prf (UInt32), iter count (UInt32), salt length (UInt32), salt, subkey } (comment out above line and uncomment below line)
    --SET @passwordVarBinStr = '0x01000000010000271000000010' + REPLACE(master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(@saltVarBin) + (SELECT dbo.fn_PBKDF2('SHA2_256', @passwordIn, @decodedsalt,10000, 32)),'0x','')


    -- Convert the password binary string to base 64
    DECLARE @passwordVarBin VARBINARY(max)
    SET @passwordVarBin =  (select cast('' as xml).value('xs:hexBinary( substring(sql:variable("@passwordVarBinStr"), sql:column("t.pos")) )', 'varbinary(max)') from (select case substring(@passwordVarBinStr, 1, 2) when '0x' then 3 else 0 end) as t(pos))
    SET @passwordOut = cast(''as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@passwordVarBin"))', 'varchar(max)')

RETURN
```

Finally execute the stored proc using

```
DECLARE @NewPassword varchar(100)
DECLARE @EncryptPassword VARCHAR(max)

select @NewPassword = 'password12344'                                           

EXECUTE EncryptPassword2 @NewPassword, @PasswordOut = @EncryptPassword OUTPUT;

PRINT @EncryptPassword
```

Please note that the stored proc may need to be changed for later versions of SQL server as this was written specifically for 2005 and I belive conversion to base64 is different in later versions.

Comment: Sorry to respond to old post, does it support SHA256 (ASP.NET Identity V3)?

Comment: It is written for v1.0. It would need to be moved to SQL 2012 which supports SHA2_256 and the format is totally different for v3.0 Format: { 0x01, prf (UInt32), iter count (UInt32), salt length (UInt32), salt, subkey }

Comment: To make the above work for v3.0 change the line `SET @passwordVarBinStr = '0x00' + REPLACE(master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(@saltVarBin) + (SELECT dbo.fn_PBKDF2('sha1', @passwordIn, @decodedsalt, 1000, 32)),'0x','')`
 to `SET @passwordVarBinStr = '0x01000000010000271000000010' +  REPLACE(master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(@saltVarBin) + (SELECT dbo.fn_PBKDF2('SHA2_256', @passwordIn, @decodedsalt,10000, 32)),'0x','')` and run on SQL 2012 or above. Worked out using Michael's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138429/hash-and-salt-passwords-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks Dave. I will try it out.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using CLR you can create this function in SQL. On this page you will find very nice example:

http://svakodnevnica.com.ba/index.php?option=com_kunena&func=view&catid=4&id=4&Itemid=5&lang=en#7

P.S. byte[] src = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);  is correct way...

Fox

Comment: I was able to tailor the example included on that page to my needs pretty easily. And for some this may be the only option since Azure doesn't support CLR extensions.

Comment: I got this to work with a single line of T-SQL and the two encode/decode functions in the above post.  Nothing else needed:

select dbo.adm_base64encode(Hashbytes('SHA1',dbo.adm_base64decode(N'<salt here>')+convert(varbinary(max),N'<cleartext password here')))

Comment: The url listed above is no longer valid.

Comment: A version of the code seems to be at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ee336f88-4055-4003-b9f7-09f4e4083070/for-everyone-tsql-to-create-default-user-in-your-lightswitch-app-with-the?forum=lightswitch but I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 4):

OP requested "pure" sql - I think using CLR is cheating ;)  I was stubborn and had to figure it out for myself so here's what I did.

NOTE: Make a backup first!!

```
Select * into dbo.aspnet_Membership_BACKUP from [dbo].[aspnet_Membership]
```

Function to calculate the hashes:

```
/*
    Create compatible hashes for the older style ASP.Net Membership

    Credit for Base64 encode/decode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082345/base64-encoding-in-sql-server-2005-t-sql
*/
Create Function dbo.AspNetHashCreate (@clearPass nvarchar(64), @encodedSalt nvarchar(64))
Returns nvarchar(128)
as
begin
    declare @binSalt varbinary(128)
    declare @binPass varbinary(128)

    declare @result nvarchar(64)

    Select @binPass = CONVERT(VARBINARY(128), @clearPass)

    --  Passed salt is Base64 so decode to bin, then we'll combine/append it with password
    Select @binSalt = CAST(N'' as XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("bin"))','VARBINARY(128)') 
        from (Select @encodedSalt as bin) as temp;

    --  Hash the salt + pass, then convert to Base64 for the output
    Select @result = CAST(N'' as XML).value('xs:base64Binary(xs:hexBinary(sql:column("bin")))', 'NVARCHAR(64)')
        from (Select HASHBYTES('SHA1', @binSalt + @binPass) as bin) as temp2;

    --  Debug, check sizes
    --Select DATALENGTH(@binSalt), DATALENGTH(@binPass), DATALENGTH(@binSalt + @binPass)

    return @result
end
```

I was changing a Membership database from "clear" passwords to the more secure hashed format - call it like this:

```
Update [dbo].[aspnet_Membership] set PasswordFormat = 1, Password = dbo.AspNetHashCreate(password, PasswordSalt) where PasswordFormat = 0
```

Even with my database originally set to "clear" passwords, the salt values were created with each record, however, if for some reason you don't have salt values you can create them with this:

```
/*
    Create compatible salts for the older style ASP.Net Membership (just a 16 byte random number in Base64)

    Note: Can't use newId() inside function so just call it like so: dbo.AspNetSaltCreate(newId())

    Credit for Base64 encode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082345/base64-encoding-in-sql-server-2005-t-sql
*/
Create Function dbo.AspNetSaltCreate (@RndId uniqueidentifier)
    Returns nvarchar(24)
as
begin
    return
        (Select CAST(N'' as XML).value('xs:base64Binary(xs:hexBinary(sql:column("bin")))', 'NVARCHAR(64)')
            from (select cast(@RndId as varbinary(16)) as bin) as temp)
end
```

Then use it like this:

```
Update [dbo].[aspnet_Membership] set PasswordSalt = dbo.AspNetSaltCreate(newId()) where PasswordSalt = ''
```

Enjoy!

Comment: This is great! I am migrating an old ASP.NET Membership and couldn't find a way to test if the migration code I got was correct and this helped me verify it :)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this SO post,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137368/what-is-default-hash-algorithm-that-asp-net-membership-uses) this is the process they use to encode/hash your password/salt.

```
public string EncodePassword(string pass, string salt)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass); //HERE
    byte[] src = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(salt); //and HERE
    byte[] dst = new byte[src.Length + bytes.Length];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 0, dst, 0, src.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, dst, src.Length, bytes.Length);
    HashAlgorithm algorithm = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA1");
    byte[] inArray = algorithm.ComputeHash(dst); //then they has the bytes not the string...
    return Convert.ToBase64String(inArray);
}
```

I could be wrong but it looks like you are missing the step where you get the bytes for the password and salt.  Can you try adding that and see if it works?

Comment: Yeah, I've been looking at that. I've tried CONVERT to varbinary, and it doesn't make any difference - it returns exactly the same result as when I don't call the convert function. If there's another way to represent that in T-SQL, I don't know it.