# T-SQL - Convert binary data to/from Base64 (or other string representation)

Tags: sql, t-sql

Is there a Microsoft T-SQL statement that will allow you to convert a binary data type (like image) to/from a string representation like Base64.

its easy enough in .net (Convert.ToBase64 & Convert.FromBase64) but is this possible using SQL alone, something like (obviously pseudocode)

```
SELECT CastAsBase64(binary_field) As Base64BinaryField
FROM   SomeTable
WHERE  ID = @ID
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082345/base64-encoding-in-sql-server-2005-t-sql

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Could not see this in the linked answers;

```
;with test(blob) as (select 0x776962626C65)

select blob from test
  for xml raw, binary base64

>>  <row blob="d2liYmxl"/>
```

Comment: perfect solution to convert binary img data to base64 string

Answer (score 3):

I had an old bookmark to this site that converts it using an xml conversion not really straightforward but it works.:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/06/30/converting-from-base64-to-varbinary-and-vice-versa.aspx