# Hash MD5 in Base64 using Queries in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, hash, base64, md5

I'm trying to generate a hash value of a specific string in MD5 Base64.
Is it possible to do it in a query within SQL Server?

I know there's a function to generate hashes in `HashBytes(Algo,String)`, but there's no Base64 option.

Is there?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Base64 encoding in SQL Server 2005 T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082345/base64-encoding-in-sql-server-2005-t-sql)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Base64Encode
(
    @bin VARBINARY(MAX)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN   
    return CAST(N'' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(xs:hexBinary(sql:variable("@bin")))', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
END

SELECT dbo.Base64Encode(HashBytes('MD5', ItemName))
FROM tblItems
```

Comment: Hi Magnus, it works! thanks!
2 questions from this though, as I am not familiar with MSSQL:

1) I just need to run this create function query once, so that the function will exist within the MSSQL database. But how do I find the function from the MSSQL Management Studio?

2) From the same MSSQL Management Studio, all select statements I used have to be something like:
select column from <DatabaseName>.<Schema>.<Table>.<column>...

how do I just specify the table.column.. or shorten the field?

Thanks!!! :)

Comment: Yes you only need to create it once, you'll find it in Management Studio beneath `Programmability --> Functions --> Scalar-Values Functions`. If you batch begins with `Use DbName` you don't have to specify it inside the query.

Comment: Hi Magnus, i notice the function appears in 'Master'.
1) How do I create a function that appears in the specific database I am working on? 
2) Is there any added advantage/disadvantage if the function is in the master database or not?
3) Even with "Use DBname", I will still need to specifiy <Schema>.<Table> under the 'from' part of the query. is that expected? 

Sorry I'm new to SO, and I must be really a blind mouse here... but I can't seem to find where can I accept the answer to acknowledge

Comment: 1. Use the `USE DbName` statement before the crate function statement. 2. Don't put it in the master. 3. You only need to specify Schema.Function not Schema.Table if the schema is dbo.

Comment: i guess i need to play around with it more to figure it out thanks!

Comment: Hi Magnus, just to clarify, you're saying after using `USE DbName` I will need to query the db or function usng Schema.Function or Schema.table respectively.

But is there anyway, within the query, I just specify the function name or table name, to simplify the queries?

Thanks!