# Exporting Attachments from Dynamics 3.0 MSSQL Table to Local Folder

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamics-crm

I am working on an ETL project, and part of the requirements is to extract email attachments from MS Dynamics CRM 3.0 for migration into Salesforce.com.

The part where I'm stumped is in extracting (i.e., saving as files in a local folder), the documents which are stored as MS SQL 2005 "Text" (Base64) objects under the DocumentBody field.

If you're familiar with MS Dynamics architecture, these are stored under the "AnnotationsBase" table. Here's an example of a query and a couple rows of output:

```
SELECT top 1
   [AnnotationId]
  ,[OwningUser]
  ,[ObjectId]
  ,[Subject]
  ,[MimeType]
  ,[DocumentBody]
  ,[FileName]
FROM [Manufacturing_Company_MSCRM].[dbo].[AnnotationBase]
where isdocument = 1
order by filesize
```

---

**AnnotationId:** 02E5D4E3-5323-DC11-ADF9-0013726038EA

**OwningUser:** DC86BB76-0A74-DB11-8659-0013726038EA

**ObjectId:** ED0A7E57-4518-DC11-8EB4-0013726038EA

**Subject:** Note created on 03/31/2009 1:19 PM by Microsoft CRM

**MimeType:** text/plain

**DocumentBody:** Rmlyc3QgTmFtZSxMYXN0IE5hbWUsRS1tYWlsIEFkZHJlc3MNCkpvaG4sU21pdGgsanNtaXRoQG1pY3Jvc29mdC5jb20NCkZyYW5rLEpvbmVzLGZqb25lc0Bjb250b3NvLmNvbQ0KLCwNCiwsDQosLA0KLCwNCiwsDQosLA0KLCwNCiwsDQosLA0KLCwNCiwsDQo=

**FileName:** bmc_import.csv

---

With many different mime types and thousands of attachments, How could I script a way to populate a folder (let's call it "C:\attachments\") with these files (like c:\attachments\bmc_import.csv, c:\attachments\budget.xls, etc.)?

Thanks.

Comment: It may help to know that `DocumentBody` is stored in `base64` format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have blogged an example of how to do this with web services in 2011. I realise this is a couple of versions ahead and is a different approach to a straight sql call but you might find it useful. I dont think the code would be vastly different in Crm 3, just how the service call is executed and the results parsed.

[Exporting Attachments Mscrm 2011](http://woodsworkblog.wordpress.com/2012/07/28/exporting-annotation-note-attachment/)

Comment: Could you clarify what language it is, what what kind of call you made to the database? It's not a SQL query.

Comment: Its a C#, WCF Soap web service call. As a I mentioned in my post its not sql.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if T-SQL has an equivalent to your function here?
  
byte[] data = convert.FromBase64String(e.Attributes["documentbody"].ToString());

Comment: This looks like it might do the trick. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082345/base64-encoding-in-sql-server-2005-t-sql

Comment: You came across the same solution I did, so that confirms it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Yaaqov I realize this is a long time ago but did you manage to export docs via SQL and if so any chance you could post the code?

Comment: @keerz Ha, this was 7 years of projects and companies ago, but James Woods' solution would be the best indication of what to do. As an aside, my ETL was Talend (an open source and Enterprise edition is available)

Comment: @Yaaqov thanks. I used the James Woods method. Believe it or not, there are companies out there still on crm 2011!!