# Extract and decode B64 encoded data from XML using Xquery

Tags: sql, xml, encoding, xquery

I have a lot of xmls with pdf data that is them and encoded with B64 encoding.

```
<Document>
    <component>
        <nonXMLBody>
          <text mediaType="application/pdf" representation="B64">JVBERi0xLjMNJf////
          </text>
        </nonXMLBody>
      </component>
</Document>
```

I have two problems:
1) figuring out the right syntax to get all of the data out.  I keep getting truncated versions.  I've tried varchar(max) and varbinary.

```
SELECT x.value('(component/nonXMLBody/text/text())[1]','varchar(max)') as 
FROM @XML.nodes('/Document') as Addr (x))
```

2) How to decode the B64 data.

I found a post that seems like it is close to what I need  but I'm still stuck.
[Base64 encoding in SQL Server 2005 T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082345/base64-encoding-in-sql-server-2005-t-sql)

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: 1) Take care of blanks and proper concatenating of rows of B64 text. Try using `fn:string()` instead of `text()` - see http://blog.davidcassel.net/2011/06/text-fnstring-and-fndata/

Answer (score 0):

As far as the XQuery part is concerned, you can (should?) cast the Base64 inside the document to an xs:base64Binary with

```
xs:base64Binary((component/nonXMLBody/text)[1])
```

assuming the document is bound with the context item as you seem to assume. Without the cast, the contents of the tag will be untyped, or a string at best.

Once you have this xs:base64Binary atomic item, I am not familiar with the binding to SQL Server types and looking at its documentation, it seems that varbinary(max) could do the trick? Something like:

```
SELECT x.value('xs:base64Binary((component/nonXMLBody/text)[1])','varbinary(max)') as 
FROM @XML.nodes('/Document') as Addr (x))
```