# base64 encode for chinese chars

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, base64, chinese-locale

I'm using both the following methods to encode in base 64 a Chinese string. Problem is that I'm having `Pz8=` as output, which decoded is `??`

What's wrong with this and how can I fix it?

Method 1

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[base64Encode] (@input VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @output NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @bits VARBINARY(3),
        @pos INT

    SET @pos = 1
    SET @output = ''

    WHILE @pos <= LEN(@input)
    BEGIN
        SET @bits = CONVERT(VARBINARY(3), SUBSTRING(@input, @pos, 3))
        SET @output = @output + SUBSTRING('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/', SUBSTRING(@bits, 1, 1) / 4 + 1, 1)
        SET @output = @output + SUBSTRING('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/', SUBSTRING(@bits, 1, 1) % 4 * 16 + SUBSTRING(@bits, 2, 1) / 16 + 1, 1)
        SET @output = @output + SUBSTRING('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/', SUBSTRING(@bits, 2, 1) % 16 * 4 + SUBSTRING(@bits, 3, 1) / 64 + 1, 1)
        SET @output = @output + SUBSTRING('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/', SUBSTRING(@bits, 3, 1) % 64 + 1, 1)
        SET @pos = @pos + 3
    END

    RETURN (LEFT(@output, LEN(@output) - 3 + LEN(@bits)) + REPLICATE('=', 3 - LEN(@bits)))
END

SELECT [dbo].[base64Encode]('你好')
```

Method 2

```
SELECT CAST('你好' as varbinary(max)) FOR XML PATH(''), BINARY BASE64
```

Comment: You're literal string is a `varchar`, not an `nvarchar`. Use `N'你好'`. If you try `SELECT '你好',N'你好';` you'll very quickly see the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `N` to mark a string literal as *unicode*:

```
 SELECT N'你好' AS unicode
       ,'你好' AS ASCII
```

Try this to get a `base64` out of your chinese charcters and vice versa:

```
SELECT (SELECT CAST(N'你好' AS VARBINARY(MAX)) FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value(N'.','nvarchar(max)');
```

You get this `base64` result: YE99WQ==

This is the way to re-convert the `base64` to the original value

```
SELECT CAST(CAST('<x>' + 'YE99WQ==' + '</x>' AS XML).value('.','varbinary(max)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX));
```

### UPDATE Some words about the re-encoding

`base64` does not encode a string value, but the binary pattern a system uses to keep that string in memory (this is valid for any data type actually). The bit pattern of a string differs with `UTF-8`, `UTF-16`, `ASCII` whatever... And even worse there is BE and LE.

The steps to get `base64` are:

- Get the bit pattern of my value (a string, a date, a picture, any value actually)
- compute the `base64` for this bit pattern

The steps for the re-encoding are

- Compute the **original** bit pattern which is *hidden* within the `base64`
- Interpret the bit pattern as the **original** value

The very last step might bring up confusion... You have to know **exactly** which binary representation a system uses. You have to use **exactly** the same data type with **exactly** the same interpretation to get the values back.

With strings one has to know, that SQL-Server works with a very limited choice natively.

- There is `NVARCHAR` (`NCHAR`), which is *2-byte encoded unicode* in `UCS-2` flavour (almost the same as `utf-16`)
- And there is `VARCHAR` (`CHAR`), which is *1-byte encoded extended ASCII*. All *non-latin* characters are bound to a code page within the connected collation. But **this is not UTF-8!**

Comment: I would add one thing to avoid confusion when some external app will decode values. SQL Server uses UTF-16 [How to decode base64 unicode string using T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25113655/how-to-decode-base64-unicode-string-using-t-sql)

Comment: @lad2025 Isn't the last part exactly doing this?

Comment: @Shnugo Yes, exactly inside SQL Server everything is OK (encode/decode). But if you encode in SQL Server and decode using for instance https://www.base64decode.org/ you will get different results.

Comment: @lad2025 is right, if i try to decode the string i've encoded with your system, with the javscript atob() function, i'm unable to decode it because the output is a string with "\u0000" between each char of the original decoded string

Comment: @Mark Read my update. Your *`\u0000` between each char* points to a writen *2-byte* string, which is read as *1-byte* string.

Comment: @Shnugo thanks for adding the explaination, but I can't find out how to correctly decode that string with javascript in documentations...do you have any idea?

Comment: @Mark You are dealing with binary values, not with strings... To avoid *cross-system* issues I'd implement an UDF in T-SQL. You might [read this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2820249/5089204)

Comment: @Shnugo I've already put the code from your answer into an UDF but I can't see how this could help decoding the generated string in javascript...

Comment: @Mark Can't you call this function from your JS code? Pass in the base64 string and get back the clear text (all in UCS-2)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172526/discussion-between-mark-and-shnugo).