# Is it possible to convert a column to Base64 in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column with emails which I would like to encode to Base64 in SQL Server.
Is it even possible to do that?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082345/base64-encoding-in-sql-server-2005-t-sql

Comment: @Dave: Do you want encryption on data column in SQL Server ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want your email column should be encrypted then follow these links For Reference.........

[Blog.SqlAuthority](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/28/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-encryption-and-symmetric-key-encryption-tutorial-with-script/)

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms179331.aspx)