# encrypt string in t-sql/decrypt on public site

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, encryption

I have a following situation.
1. I need to encrypt set of strings in t-sql. These encrypted strings will be manually delivered to users.
2. Users have neither knowledge nor access to sql server. I'd like them to go to a website copy/paste the hash and get the original string.

- There are no security requirements. Just that the hash doesn't look like original string
- On the other hand it's important that access to the website and decrypting process is ultra-easy for the users.
- Do you know what t-sql function I can use(it can be user defined)
- What website

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand requirements correctly. Do you want to create this website or use an existing one (that was created by someone else)?

Comment: I want to use a website, available publicly. I'm not a programmer, only sql-developer.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you want to encrypt in your application, and send the encrypted hash to the database.

But there are several ways of encrypting strings in sql server

For example, you can use EncryptByPassPhrase, and DecryptByPassPhrse.

[image]

More information here: [EncryptByPassPhrase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190357.aspx), and [DecryptByPassPhrse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188910.aspx)

Or you can encrypt using something simple like MD5, and they can go to an MD5 decrypter online.

[image]

I'm assuming your making the site, so you should easily be able to encrypt, and have the decryption done on the site.

Comment: .Yep. I know these functions. do you know of any public website which would decrypt these hashes?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using base64 encoding. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082345/base64-encoding-in-sql-server-2005-t-sql) question explains how to convert input text into base64 string in T-SQL. For example `TestData` will be converted into 'VGVzdERhdGE='. There are also many online base64 decoders which will perform the inverse task and decode'VGVzdERhdGE=' into 'TestData'. For example see [this one](https://www.base64decode.org/).

Of course base64 doesn't provide any security. It only changes the representation of the input text. It means that everyone who will receive the encoded string will be able to decode it.