# How to generate a GUID string in the same format as Advantage Database Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, guid, advantage-database-server

I have an advantage database V11 in which I currently store a unique identifier which is a GUID string generated 22 characters long using NewIDString('F').

The snippet from the ADS help is as follows :-

*"F or File – A GUID encoded as a 22-byte string using File and URL Safe base64 encoding with the format of xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. Base64 encoded strings are case sensitive and should not be stored in case insensitive string fields."*

Is it possible to generate the same format GUID string in Microsoft SQL?

If not, the ADS Help file lists other formats as follows :-

*NEWIDSTRING
 Returns a GUID formatted as a string. If the format parameter is not specified, the GUID string is formatted as a hexadecimal string with the following pattern xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx. The format parameter can be the following values:*

*M or MIME – A GUID encoded as a 24-byte string using MIME base64 encoding with the format of xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. Base64 encoded strings are case sensitive and should not be stored in case insensitive string fields.*

*F or File – A GUID encoded as a 22-byte string using File and URL Safe base64 encoding with the format of xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. Base64 encoded strings are case sensitive and should not be stored in case insensitive string fields.*

*N or Numbers – A GUID encoded as a 32-byte hexadecimal string value with a format of xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.*

*D or Delimited – A GUID encoded as a 32-byte hexadecimal string with a format of xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx.*

*B or Bracketed – A GUID encoded as a 32-byte hexadecimal string with a format of [xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx]*

*P or Parenthesis – A GUID encoded as a 32-byte hexadecimal string with a format of (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)*

*C or Curlybraces – A GUID encoded as a 32-byte hexadecimal string with a format of {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}*

Can MS-SQL generate one of these?

Regards

Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL SerVer the [NEWID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx) function creates new GUIDs (the SQL Server data type is called [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx)). A GUID is a binary value, the various formats you mention in your question are just that, merely different string representations of the binary value. In the MSDN page for NEWID example A shows the standard string representation of a GUID as XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX.

Comment: Which is exactly `UPPER(NEWIDSTRING(D))` in ADS

Comment: N, B, P and C are all just variations on that, you can get those using string manipulation. For M and F see my answer.

Comment: Thank you both. That is perfect. I just want consistency and the same size in both databases.

Answer (score 3):

Creationg BASE64 encoded strings in SQL-Server is not straight forward, [but possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082345/base64-encoding-in-sql-server-2005-t-sql).

So everything you need to create a GUID in the form `File` format from ADS can be produced by SQL-Server.

NEWIDSTRING(M):

```
-- Generate a GUID in the format "1Jg/YZ7tNkG7PQr1wVe7KA=="
SELECT
    CAST(N'' AS XML).value(
          'xs:base64Binary(xs:hexBinary(sql:column("bin")))'
        , 'VARCHAR(MAX)'
    ) AS "NEWIDSTRING_M"
FROM (
    SELECT CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS bin
) AS bin_sql_server_temp;
```

NEWIDSTRING(F):

```
-- Generate a GUID in the format "1Jg/YZ7tNkG7PQr1wVe7KA"
SELECT
    LEFT(CAST(N'' AS XML).value(
          'xs:base64Binary(xs:hexBinary(sql:column("bin")))'
        , 'VARCHAR(MAX)'
    ), 22) AS "NEWIDSTRING_F"
FROM (
    SELECT CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS bin
) AS bin_sql_server_temp;
```

Where F is just M with the last two characters (which are always "==") removed.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will stick  with the standard 36 chars one from your first answer.