# sql server select as base64 column

Tags: sql-server, base64

Is there any simple function for get this output.

```
SELECT Title FROM Table WHERE Id = 1 
---- My title
```

Desire function or etc ...

```
SELECT MYBASE64ENCODE(Title) FROM Table WHERE Id = 1 
---- TXkgdGl0bGU=
```

I need the function for ecnode string to base64.

If answer is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082345/base64-encoding-in-sql-server-2005-t-sql) so how can put my column as input of my query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Base64 encoding in SQL Server 2005 T-SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082345/base64-encoding-in-sql-server-2005-t-sql)

Comment: @JamesZ i dot thinks so it's an complex query i need the function not select inside select.

Comment: Did you read it? There's also function examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe create a User-defined function something like this.....

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.get_base64Coded (@Input nvarchar(4000))
RETURNS  nvarchar(4000)
AS
BEGIN
  Declare @Output nvarchar(4000);

SELECT
   @Output = CAST(N'' AS XML).value(
          'xs:base64Binary(xs:hexBinary(sql:column("value")))'
        , 'VARCHAR(MAX)')   
FROM (
       SELECT CAST(@Input AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS value
     ) AS A;
  RETURN @Output      
END
```

Your query would look something like...

```
SELECT dbo.get_base64Coded(Title) FROM Table WHERE Id = 1
```

Comment: Alternative function body, `DECLARE @InputBinary varbinary(MAX) = CAST(@Input AS varbinary(MAX)); 

RETURN CAST(N'' AS XML).value(
          'xs:base64Binary(xs:hexBinary(sql:variable("@InputBinary")))'
        , 'VARCHAR(4000)');`