# Inserting base64 string as varbinary yelding incorrect value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, base64

I am encoding an image to a base64 string using powershell. The encoding is working ok as I have testing it using

```
<img src="data:image/JPEG;charset=utf-8;base64, <base64string>">
```

Now I am attempting to update an SQL Server 2012 table with the base64 string using the following update statement:

```
update images set ImageBlob = convert(varbinary(MAX),<base64string>)
```

I have also tried to cast it to varbinary

```
update images set ImageBlob = cast(<base64string>, as varbinary(max))
```

When the update script runs I check the field value and the value is completely different than what i expected. The image will also not render on my page at all.

Am i doing something wrong when I attempt to load it into my database?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use varchar(max)?

Comment: I assumed saving them as varbinary was best for performance and database capacity? If it doesn't matter I will store it as varchar(max) which I have done and it works fine.

Comment: I don't believe there will be any different retrieving varchar versus varbinary,  You could do a quick benchmark but to the best of my knowledge it won't make a difference...  The other option is not to encode the image and store it as binary in a varbinary.  If you need to you can encode/decode as here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082345/base64-encoding-in-sql-server-2005-t-sql