# Why BASE64 string is not getting decoded in sql 2012?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, base64

I have Encoded my string to Base64 representation and storing it in VARCHAR(MAX) column in sql 2012's db.

Now I am trying to decode the value using this:

```
Declare @FMoney varchar(max)

Set @FMoney= (Select FinancialMoney from  AppliedWorks aw
where AppliedWorkID= 20082)

SELECT CAST( CAST( @FMoney as XML ).value('.','varbinary(max)') AS varchar(max) )
```

But it doesn't give me the original value and gives a long another base64 string.

Note: The value stored in db is encoded via C#.net and sent to db (**anhhZWRzaGFzYjJuenVka2J1aWRqcjM1fDE1LjAw**) but decoding should be performed in sql.

C# Encoding Code:

```
public static String Encrypt(string strData)
    {
        if (strData != "")
        {
            strData = string.Format("{0}|{1}", HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID, strData);
            SHA1Managed shaM = new SHA1Managed();
            Convert.ToBase64String(shaM.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strData)));
            Byte[] encByteData;
            encByteData = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strData);
            String encStrData = Convert.ToBase64String(encByteData);
            return encStrData;
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }

    }
```

Update: I have added c#.net's decoding procedure also.

```
 public static String Decrypt(string strData)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strData) == false)
        {
            Byte[] decByteData;
            decByteData = Convert.FromBase64String(strData);
            String decStrData = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(decByteData);

            String[] SplitValue = decStrData.Split('|');

            String ReturnValue = SplitValue[1];
            return ReturnValue;
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }

    }
```

The c# side works fine for ENCODING and DECODING but what I am trying to do it sot encode in c# and decode in sql.

Comment: You don't assign the result of  `Convert.ToBase64String(shaM.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strData)));` to anything?  UTF8 may be wiser than ASCII as an encoder.

Comment: no, and it works fine but the problem is on sql side since it doesn't decode the encoded value

Comment: Change it to use UTF8.GetBytes/String - this will fix things like a `£` symbol breaking, if that does not work can you share sample input/output at all stages.

Comment: Your Encrypt method really isn't encrypting. Even if you were using the result of calling `ComputeHash`, that would be hashing rather than encrypting. Why are you even bothering to encode in base64 when you start with text and end with text?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Base64 encoding in SQL Server 2005 T-SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082345/base64-encoding-in-sql-server-2005-t-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `xs:base64Binary` function from the `SELECT` statement

```
SELECT CAST( CAST( @FMoney as XML ).value('xs:base64Binary(.)','varbinary(max)') AS varchar(max) )
```

returns

```
jxaedshasb2nzudkbuidjr35|15.00
```