# SQL Server/Dynamics CRM: How to read document body from Annotation Base using SQL only

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, dynamics-crm, type-conversion

I am building an SSRS report in which I need to read parts of a MS Word Document body that contains some error logs.  The document body is stored in the AnnotationBase in SQL Server.  Per Scott Durow (MVP),

> "The DocumentBody is a base64 encoded string, so you'll need to
>   convert back to binary and save to a file."

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/185391

I am aware there is a converter and have also tried the following using SQL:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqltips/2008/06/30/converting-from-base64-to-varbinary-and-vice-versa/

However the solution in the above link did not work.

I am aware this can easily done using C#.  However, this is the only snag I have ran into building the report and would like to keep it all SQL.

Is this possible without me having to right a .NET component?  If not, can this be done using FetchXML?

Comment: what are CRM and SQL version ?

Comment: CRM 2015 on-prem, SQL 2014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decode the Base64 `documentbody` column in SQL as shown here: [Base64 encoding in SQL Server 2005 T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082345/base64-encoding-in-sql-server-2005-t-sql)

```
-- Encode the string "TestData" in Base64 to get "VGVzdERhdGE="
SELECT
    CAST(N'' AS XML).value(
          'xs:base64Binary(xs:hexBinary(sql:column("bin")))'
        , 'VARCHAR(MAX)'
    )   Base64Encoding
FROM (
    SELECT CAST('TestData' AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS bin
) AS bin_sql_server_temp;

-- Decode the Base64-encoded string "VGVzdERhdGE=" to get back "TestData"
SELECT 
    CAST(
        CAST(N'' AS XML).value(
            'xs:base64Binary("VGVzdERhdGE=")'
          , 'VARBINARY(MAX)'
        ) 
        AS VARCHAR(MAX)
    )   ASCIIEncoding
;
```

(Aside, you should avoid using the `Base` tables, it's not supported, use the Filtered tables instead `FilteredAnnotation`).

(Also aside, the Word document is structured as complex XML which may difficult to parse in SQL, so perhaps this isnt the best solution in any case.)