# Error when trying to insert a varbinary in an sql-server db table

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to insert an entry into a table that contain a binary image with this query:

```
INSERT INTO [AlphaDb].[dbo].[ImageThumbnail] (id, imageLinkFunctionId, thumbnail, byDefault)
VALUES ('8da33b6b-ff9e-41be-83d9-ede6edfbb53a', 'a00dbde1-a6be-4f29-b9fc-3d5eb1082c11', 
CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgICAgMCAgIDAwMDBAYEBAQEBAgGBgUGCQgKCgkI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',2), 'true')
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to varbinary.
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? What are the possible values for the style parameter? Hint - not 'true'.

Comment: That's wrong - I see the style now. But the following bit about 'true' has no reason for existence.

Comment: @SMor I want to insert value for 4 columns. I need 'true' for the byDefault column.

Comment: Your style indicates the literal is hex - but it is not. There are additional requirements as well (even number of characters)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to convert Base64-encoded data. [Would you like some help with that?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32231832/41379160)

Comment: @neptune: As Jeroen said you are trying to convert base64 data and you have specified style in `CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),.., 2)` <- If you remove this style than your query successfully convert those values onto varbinary. like this - `CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), 'your value')`.

Comment: @KrishnrajRana: that will convert the ASCII representation of the string into a `VARBINARY`, which will certainly allow you to store it, but is not the actual image, and hence almost certainly not what you want (otherwise, you could have just made the column a `VARCHAR(MAX)`).