# Encrypt and Decrypt a String value with return type as String

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, encryption

I would like to have a function in sql that encrypts a given `varchar` value and returns it as a `varchar` and Vice-versa. I have checked out the following functions of sql such as :

`ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE`  `ENCRYPTBYKEY`  `ENCRYPTBYCERT`

I have also checked out other questions here but I am unable to find (or maybe understand) the solution I am looking for. What I want to do is pass the encrypted string to a URL as query string (I would like this to do this from Db) which does not have any `/` so that it does not mess with the URL routes.

Step 1: I made random string generator. (Works)

```
DECLARE @RandomString VARCHAR (500) = ( SELECT RandomString
                                        FROM   dbo.SfRandomStringGenerator (64, 1) );
```

Example string:
`X922t1N2udpdi30HZN9W4U9N997UatHZMJKWvI4si0w9g9q6FA3Lqd8NxCJXAe5D`

Step 2: I would like to encrypt the string from Step 1 so that the Output is also in String format BUT the Encryption methods that I have come across all return VARBINARY which is not what I Want.

```
Declare @EncryptedString Nvarchar(MAX)=dbo.SfEncrypt(@RandomString)
Select @EncryptedString
```

Example string:
`WDkyMnQxTjJ1ZHBkaTMwSFpOOVc0VTlOOTk3VWF0SFpNSktXdkk0c2kwdzlnOXE2RkEzTHFkOE54Q0pYQWU1RA`

Step 3: I would also like to be able to decrypt the encrypted string.

```
Declare @DecryptedString Nvarchar(MAX)=dbo.SfDecrypt(@RandomString)
Select @DecryptedString
```

Example string:
`X922t1N2udpdi30HZN9W4U9N997UatHZMJKWvI4si0w9g9q6FA3Lqd8NxCJXAe5D`

Thus far I have not been able to get the encryption I want.
Any help or pointers towards the solution would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't understand the documentation, what about it don't you understand? What have you done so far, and what didn't work?

Comment: @Larnu , Made changes to the question. Please check.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It appears that you are asking how to `convert` (or `cast`) a `VarBinary` to a `VarChar`.

Comment: @HABO No. I am not looking for a Cast or Convert. But thank you for the improvement link.

Answer (score 0):

Read the VARBINARY result into a byte[] array.

Convert the byte[] array into a Base 64 string using System.Convert.ToBase64String()

Base64 includes the `+` and `/` characters which have special meaning in a url path, so they must be encoded.

UrlEncode the base 64 string using System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string) to encode any `+` or `/` characters with `%2B` or `%2F`.

You should then be able to add the url-encoded string to your url.

On the url endpoint, reverse the procedure to obtain the original encrypted byte[] array.

**EDIT**: Be aware that using a query string can come up against a length limit, of the order of 2048 characters, so if your data is larger than this, you may find that the server will refuse to handle the request.

In that case, consider using POST to send your data, and supply the encrypted data in the body of the message request.

**EDIT** in response to comment:

I figured that you would be processing the result of your "do encryption" query before sending it to a server as a url, and so the fact that the SQL encryption functions return varbinary should not have presented a problem.

*IF* you are happy that you can actually do encryption and decryption in TSQL, then I'll refer you to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082345/base64-encoding-in-sql-server-2005-t-sql) SO post which offers a way to do Base-64 encoding and decoding in TSQL care of the xml query api. Do your encryption to a varbinary field, run it through the example to generate a base64 varchar, and then use TSQL `REPLACE` to convert '+' to '%2B' and '/' to '%2F'

You'll then have a varchar value of a url-encoded, base-64 encoded, encrypted representation of your input data, safe for transmission as a query string.

Comment: You are telling me the C# way and I am actually looking for a SQL way. Also, I want encrypt the string rather than just encode.

Comment: There is a URL safe version of Base-64 described in RFC 4648, section 5.  It uses minus '-' and underline '_' in place of '+' and '/' in standard Base-64.  You might find that version more useful if you want to include the output in a URL.

Comment: @Sudeep Fair comment - I've amended my reply