# Is there a SQL implementation of PBKDF2?

Tags: sql, pbkdf2

Does anyone know of a SQL implementation of [PBKDF2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898#section-5.2)?

(I'd rather not use an external library like, for example, [ChillKat's ActiveX](http://www.example-code.com/sql/crypt2_pbkdf2.asp) component.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PBKDF2 is built into the .NET framework as [System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx).  It's straightforward to create a SQL CLR function that wraps a call to this class' `GetBytes` method.

I realize you were looking for a solution that doesn't require an external library but at least this limits the dependency an assembly that simply wraps framework code.

Comment: Unfortunately this wont work on an Azure SQL database as you can't use the .NET CLR

Answer (score 18):

Here's a dramatically faster PBKDF2/PKCS #5/RFC2898 implementation of PBKDF2(HMAC-SHA-512..., useful on SQL2012 and up, including StackOverflow and boundary size test vectors.  Much of the speed increase is the usual precalculation of ipad and opad, reducing the number of hashing operations dramatically.  The rest is normal code optimization, loop unrolling, and so on.

```
USE tempdb; -- in case YourDB does not exist
USE YourDB;
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'[dbo].[Yourfn_CRYPT_PBKDF2_VARBINARY_SHA512]') AND xtype IN (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF'))
DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[Yourfn_CRYPT_PBKDF2_VARBINARY_SHA512]
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Yourfn_CRYPT_PBKDF2_VARBINARY_SHA512]
  (
  @Password VARBINARY(4000), -- HASHBYTES is limited, and HMAC concatenation limits this more, though 4000 is a guess
  @Salt VARBINARY(4000), -- HASHBYTES is limited, and HMAC concatenation limits this more, though 4000 is a guess
  @IterationCount INT,
  @Outputbytes INT -- For password hashing, should "naturally" be the digest size (or less) - more than the digest size allows the first <digest size> to remain identical, so someone cracking the PBKDF2'd passwords only needs to generate and check the first <digest size>
  )
RETURNS VARBINARY(8000)
AS
BEGIN
-- WARNING - if you are using SQL 2012 or better, DO NOT USE Yourfn_CRYPT_PBKDF2_VARBINARY_SHA1 UNLESS YOU NEED BACKWARDS COMPATIBILITY!!!  The 64-bit math required by SHA-512 (and SHA-384) is proportionally faster on CPUs vs. GPU's as of 2013, which reduces a GPU based attacker's advantage.
-- SEE PKCS #5, RFC2898, as well as PBKDF2, i.e. http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt
-- WARNING - SQL is NOT a good language for this type of math; results are fairly slow, and are generally better off being implemented by another language.
-- This is a dedicated HMAC-SHA-512 version, with a moderate amount of performance tuning.

/*
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @Result VARBINARY(64)
DECLARE @start DATETIME2(7)
SET @start = SYSDATETIME()
PRINT 'SHA-512 Test 1 from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593184/pbkdf2-hmac-sha-512-test-vectors'
SET @Result = YourDB.dbo.Yourfn_CRYPT_PBKDF2_VARBINARY_SHA512(CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'password'),CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'salt'),1,64)
SELECT @Result
PRINT CASE WHEN @Result IS NULL THEN 'NULL - BAD ALGO?' WHEN @Result = 0x867f70cf1ade02cff3752599a3a53dc4af34c7a669815ae5d513554e1c8cf252c02d470a285a0501bad999bfe943c08f050235d7d68b1da55e63f73b60a57fce THEN 'PASS' ELSE 'FAIL INVALID RESULT' END

PRINT 'SHA-512 Test 2 from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593184/pbkdf2-hmac-sha-512-test-vectors'
SET @Result = YourDB.dbo.Yourfn_CRYPT_PBKDF2_VARBINARY_SHA512(CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'password'),CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'salt'),2,64)
SELECT @Result
PRINT CASE WHEN @Result IS NULL THEN 'NULL - BAD ALGO?' WHEN @Result = 0xe1d9c16aa681708a45f5c7c4e215ceb66e011a2e9f0040713f18aefdb866d53cf76cab2868a39b9f7840edce4fef5a82be67335c77a6068e04112754f27ccf4e THEN 'PASS' ELSE 'FAIL INVALID RESULT' END

PRINT 'SHA-512 Test 3 from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593184/pbkdf2-hmac-sha-512-test-vectors'
SET @Result = YourDB.dbo.Yourfn_CRYPT_PBKDF2_VARBINARY_SHA512(CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'password'),CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'salt'),4096,64)
SELECT @Result
PRINT CASE WHEN @Result IS NULL THEN 'NULL - BAD ALGO?' WHEN @Result = 0xd197b1b33db0143e018b12f3d1d1479e6cdebdcc97c5c0f87f6902e072f457b5143f30602641b3d55cd335988cb36b84376060ecd532e039b742a239434af2d5 THEN 'PASS' ELSE 'FAIL INVALID RESULT' END

PRINT 'SHA-512 Test 4 from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593184/pbkdf2-hmac-sha-512-test-vectors'
SET @Result = YourDB.dbo.Yourfn_CRYPT_PBKDF2_VARBINARY_SHA512(CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'passwordPASSWORDpassword'),CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'saltSALTsaltSALTsaltSALTsaltSALTsalt'),4096,64)
SELECT @Result
PRINT CASE WHEN @Result IS NULL THEN 'NULL - BAD ALGO?' WHEN @Result = 0x8c0511f4c6e597c6ac6315d8f0362e225f3c501495ba23b868c005174dc4ee71115b59f9e60cd9532fa33e0f75aefe30225c583a186cd82bd4daea9724a3d3b8 THEN 'PASS' ELSE 'FAIL INVALID RESULT' END
PRINT 'Duration (ms): ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(23),DATEDIFF(ms,@start,SYSDATETIME()))


PRINT 'Long Test 1a 1 iter Len19pw Len19sa- validated against a Python implemenation of PBKDF2'
SET @Result = YourDB.dbo.Yourfn_CRYPT_PBKDF2_VARBINARY_SHA512(CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'passDATAb00AB7YxDTT'),CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD'),1,64)
SELECT @Result
PRINT CASE WHEN @Result IS NULL THEN 'NULL - BAD ALGO?' WHEN @Result = 0xCBE6088AD4359AF42E603C2A33760EF9D4017A7B2AAD10AF46F992C660A0B461ECB0DC2A79C2570941BEA6A08D15D6887E79F32B132E1C134E9525EEDDD744FA THEN 'PASS' ELSE 'FAIL INVALID RESULT' END

PRINT 'Long Test 1b 100000 iter Len19pw Len19sa- validated against a Python implemenation of PBKDF2'
SET @Result = YourDB.dbo.Yourfn_CRYPT_PBKDF2_VARBINARY_SHA512(CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'passDATAb00AB7YxDTT'),CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD'),100000,64)
SELECT @Result
PRINT CASE WHEN @Result IS NULL THEN 'NULL - BAD ALGO?' WHEN @Result = 0xACCDCD8798AE5CD85804739015EF2A11E32591B7B7D16F76819B30B0D49D80E1ABEA6C9822B80A1FDFE421E26F5603ECA8A47A64C9A004FB5AF8229F762FF41F THEN 'PASS' ELSE 'FAIL INVALID RESULT' END

PRINT 'Long Test 2a 1 iter Len20pw Len20sa- validated against a Python implemenation of PBKDF2'
SET @Result = YourDB.dbo.Yourfn_CRYPT_PBKDF2_VARBINARY_SHA512(CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTl'),CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2'),1,64)
SELECT @Result
PRINT CASE WHEN @Result IS NULL THEN 'NULL - BAD ALGO?' WHEN @Result = 0x8E5074A9513C1F1512C9B1DF1D8BFFA9D8B4EF9105DFC16681222839560FB63264BED6AABF761F180E912A66E0B53D65EC88F6A1519E14804EBA6DC9DF137007 THEN 'PASS' ELSE 'FAIL INVALID RESULT' END

PRINT 'Long Test 2b 100000 iter Len20pw Len20sa- validated against a Python implemenation of PBKDF2'
SET @Result = YourDB.dbo.Yourfn_CRYPT_PBKDF2_VARBINARY_SHA512(CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTl'),CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2'),100000,64)
SELECT @Result
PRINT CASE WHEN @Result IS NULL THEN 'NULL - BAD ALGO?' WHEN @Result = 0x594256B0BD4D6C9F21A87F7BA5772A791A10E6110694F44365CD94670E57F1AECD797EF1D1001938719044C7F018026697845EB9AD97D97DE36AB8786AAB5096 THEN 'PASS' ELSE 'FAIL INVALID RESULT' END

PRINT 'Long Test 3a 1 iter Len21pw Len21sa- validated against a Python implemenation of PBKDF2'
SET @Result = YourDB.dbo.Yourfn_CRYPT_PBKDF2_VARBINARY_SHA512(CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlR'),CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2P'),1,64)
SELECT @Result
PRINT CASE WHEN @Result IS NULL THEN 'NULL - BAD ALGO?' WHEN @Result = 0xA6AC8C048A7DFD7B838DA88F22C3FAB5BFF15D7CB8D83A62C6721A8FAF6903EAB6152CB7421026E36F2FFEF661EB4384DC276495C71B5CAB72E1C1A38712E56B THEN 'PASS' ELSE 'FAIL INVALID RESULT' END

PRINT 'Long Test 3b 100000 iter Len21pw Len21sa- validated against and a Javascript Python implemenation of PBKDF2'
SET @Result = YourDB.dbo.Yourfn_CRYPT_PBKDF2_VARBINARY_SHA512(CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlR'),CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2P'),100000,64)
SELECT @Result
PRINT CASE WHEN @Result IS NULL THEN 'NULL - BAD ALGO?' WHEN @Result = 0x94FFC2B1A390B7B8A9E6A44922C330DB2B193ADCF082EECD06057197F35931A9D0EC0EE5C660744B50B61F23119B847E658D179A914807F4B8AB8EB9505AF065 THEN 'PASS' ELSE 'FAIL INVALID RESULT' END

PRINT 'Long Test 4a 1 iter Len63pw Len63sa- validated against a Python implemenation of PBKDF2'
SET @Result = YourDB.dbo.Yourfn_CRYPT_PBKDF2_VARBINARY_SHA512(CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE5'),CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJe'),1,64)
SELECT @Result
PRINT CASE WHEN @Result IS NULL THEN 'NULL - BAD ALGO?' WHEN @Result = 0xE2CCC7827F1DD7C33041A98906A8FD7BAE1920A55FCB8F831683F14F1C3979351CB868717E5AB342D9A11ACF0B12D3283931D609B06602DA33F8377D1F1F9902 THEN 'PASS' ELSE 'FAIL INVALID RESULT' END

PRINT 'Long Test 4b 100000 iter Len63pw Len63sa- validated against a Python implemenation of PBKDF2'
SET @Result = YourDB.dbo.Yourfn_CRYPT_PBKDF2_VARBINARY_SHA512(CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE5'),CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJe'),100000,64)
SELECT @Result
PRINT CASE WHEN @Result IS NULL THEN 'NULL - BAD ALGO?' WHEN @Result = 0x07447401C85766E4AED583DE2E6BF5A675EABE4F3618281C95616F4FC1FDFE6ECBC1C3982789D4FD941D6584EF534A78BD37AE02555D9455E8F089FDB4DFB6BB THEN 'PASS' ELSE 'FAIL INVALID RESULT' END

PRINT 'Long Test 5a 1 iter Len64pw Len64sa- validated against a Python implemenation of PBKDF2'
SET @Result = YourDB.dbo.Yourfn_CRYPT_PBKDF2_VARBINARY_SHA512(CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57'),CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJem'),1,64)
SELECT @Result
PRINT CASE WHEN @Result IS NULL THEN 'NULL - BAD ALGO?' WHEN @Result = 0xB029A551117FF36977F283F579DC7065B352266EA243BDD3F920F24D4D141ED8B6E02D96E2D3BDFB76F8D77BA8F4BB548996AD85BB6F11D01A015CE518F9A717 THEN 'PASS' ELSE 'FAIL INVALID RESULT' END

PRINT 'Long Test 5b 100000 iter Len64pw Len64sa- validated against a Python implemenation of PBKDF2'
SET @Result = YourDB.dbo.Yourfn_CRYPT_PBKDF2_VARBINARY_SHA512(CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57'),CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJem'),100000,64)
SELECT @Result
PRINT CASE WHEN @Result IS NULL THEN 'NULL - BAD ALGO?' WHEN @Result = 0x31F5CC83ED0E948C05A15735D818703AAA7BFF3F09F5169CAF5DBA6602A05A4D5CFF5553D42E82E40516D6DC157B8DAEAE61D3FEA456D964CB2F7F9A63BBBDB5 THEN 'PASS' ELSE 'FAIL INVALID RESULT' END

PRINT 'Long Test 6a 1 iter Len65pw Len65sa- validated against a Python implemenation of PBKDF2'
SET @Result = YourDB.dbo.Yourfn_CRYPT_PBKDF2_VARBINARY_SHA512(CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57U'),CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJemk'),1,64)
SELECT @Result
PRINT CASE WHEN @Result IS NULL THEN 'NULL - BAD ALGO?' WHEN @Result = 0x28B8A9F644D6800612197BB74DF460272E2276DE8CC07AC4897AC24DBC6EB77499FCAF97415244D9A29DA83FC347D09A5DBCFD6BD63FF6E410803DCA8A900AB6 THEN 'PASS' ELSE 'FAIL INVALID RESULT' END

PRINT 'Long Test 6b 100000 iter Len65pw Len65sa- validated against a Python implemenation of PBKDF2'
SET @Result = YourDB.dbo.Yourfn_CRYPT_PBKDF2_VARBINARY_SHA512(CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57U'),CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJemk'),100000,64)
SELECT @Result
PRINT CASE WHEN @Result IS NULL THEN 'NULL - BAD ALGO?' WHEN @Result = 0x056BC9072A356B7D4DA60DD66F5968C2CAA375C0220EDA6B47EF8E8D105ED68B44185FE9003FBBA49E2C84240C9E8FD3F5B2F4F6512FD936450253DB37D10028 THEN 'PASS' ELSE 'FAIL INVALID RESULT' END

PRINT 'Long Test 7a 1 iter Len127pw Len127sa- validated against a Python implemenation of PBKDF2'
SET @Result = YourDB.dbo.Yourfn_CRYPT_PBKDF2_VARBINARY_SHA512(CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57Un4u12D2YD7oOPpiEvCDYvntXEe4NNPLCnGGeJArbYDEu6xDoCfWH6kbuV6awi0'),CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJemkURWoqHusIeVB8Il91NjiCGQacPUu9qTFaShLbKG0Yj4RCMV56WPj7E14EMpbxy'),1,64)
SELECT @Result
PRINT CASE WHEN @Result IS NULL THEN 'NULL - BAD ALGO?' WHEN @Result = 0x16226C85E4F8D604573008BFE61C10B6947B53990450612DD4A3077F7DEE2116229E68EFD1DF6D73BD3C6D07567790EEA1E8B2AE9A1B046BE593847D9441A1B7 THEN 'PASS' ELSE 'FAIL INVALID RESULT' END

PRINT 'Long Test 7b 100000 iter Len127pw Len127sa- validated against a Python implemenation of PBKDF2'
SET @Result = YourDB.dbo.Yourfn_CRYPT_PBKDF2_VARBINARY_SHA512(CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57Un4u12D2YD7oOPpiEvCDYvntXEe4NNPLCnGGeJArbYDEu6xDoCfWH6kbuV6awi0'),CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJemkURWoqHusIeVB8Il91NjiCGQacPUu9qTFaShLbKG0Yj4RCMV56WPj7E14EMpbxy'),100000,64)
SELECT @Result
PRINT CASE WHEN @Result IS NULL THEN 'NULL - BAD ALGO?' WHEN @Result = 0x70CF39F14C4CAF3C81FA288FB46C1DB52D19F72722F7BC84F040676D3371C89C11C50F69BCFBC3ACB0AB9E92E4EF622727A916219554B2FA121BEDDA97FF3332 THEN 'PASS' ELSE 'FAIL INVALID RESULT' END

PRINT 'Long Test 8a 1 iter Len128pw Len128sa- validated against a Python implemenation of PBKDF2'
SET @Result = YourDB.dbo.Yourfn_CRYPT_PBKDF2_VARBINARY_SHA512(CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57Un4u12D2YD7oOPpiEvCDYvntXEe4NNPLCnGGeJArbYDEu6xDoCfWH6kbuV6awi04'),CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJemkURWoqHusIeVB8Il91NjiCGQacPUu9qTFaShLbKG0Yj4RCMV56WPj7E14EMpbxy6'),1,64)
SELECT @Result
PRINT CASE WHEN @Result IS NULL THEN 'NULL - BAD ALGO?' WHEN @Result = 0x880C58C316D3A5B9F05977AB9C60C10ABEEBFAD5CE89CAE62905C1C4F80A0A098D82F95321A6220F8AECCFB45CE6107140899E8D655306AE6396553E2851376C THEN 'PASS' ELSE 'FAIL INVALID RESULT' END

PRINT 'Long Test 8b 100000 iter Len128pw Len128sa- validated against a Python implemenation of PBKDF2'
SET @Result = YourDB.dbo.Yourfn_CRYPT_PBKDF2_VARBINARY_SHA512(CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57Un4u12D2YD7oOPpiEvCDYvntXEe4NNPLCnGGeJArbYDEu6xDoCfWH6kbuV6awi04'),CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJemkURWoqHusIeVB8Il91NjiCGQacPUu9qTFaShLbKG0Yj4RCMV56WPj7E14EMpbxy6'),100000,64)
SELECT @Result
PRINT CASE WHEN @Result IS NULL THEN 'NULL - BAD ALGO?' WHEN @Result = 0x2668B71B3CA56136B5E87F30E098F6B4371CB5ED95537C7A073DAC30A2D5BE52756ADF5BB2F4320CB11C4E16B24965A9C790DEF0CBC62906920B4F2EB84D1D4A THEN 'PASS' ELSE 'FAIL INVALID RESULT' END

PRINT 'Long Test 9a 1 iter Len129pw Len129sa- validated against a Python implemenation of PBKDF2'
SET @Result = YourDB.dbo.Yourfn_CRYPT_PBKDF2_VARBINARY_SHA512(CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57Un4u12D2YD7oOPpiEvCDYvntXEe4NNPLCnGGeJArbYDEu6xDoCfWH6kbuV6awi04U'),CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJemkURWoqHusIeVB8Il91NjiCGQacPUu9qTFaShLbKG0Yj4RCMV56WPj7E14EMpbxy6P'),1,64)
SELECT @Result
PRINT CASE WHEN @Result IS NULL THEN 'NULL - BAD ALGO?' WHEN @Result = 0x93B9BA8283CC17D50EF3B44820828A258A996DE258225D24FB59990A6D0DE82DFB3FE2AC201952100E4CC8F06D883A9131419C0F6F5A6ECB8EC821545F14ADF1 THEN 'PASS' ELSE 'FAIL INVALID RESULT' END

PRINT 'Long Test 9b 100000 iter Len129pw Len129sa- validated against a Python implemenation of PBKDF2'
SET @Result = YourDB.dbo.Yourfn_CRYPT_PBKDF2_VARBINARY_SHA512(CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57Un4u12D2YD7oOPpiEvCDYvntXEe4NNPLCnGGeJArbYDEu6xDoCfWH6kbuV6awi04U'),CONVERT(VARBINARY(4000),'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJemkURWoqHusIeVB8Il91NjiCGQacPUu9qTFaShLbKG0Yj4RCMV56WPj7E14EMpbxy6P'),100000,64)
SELECT @Result
PRINT CASE WHEN @Result IS NULL THEN 'NULL - BAD ALGO?' WHEN @Result = 0x2575B485AFDF37C260B8F3386D33A60ED929993C9D48AC516EC66B87E06BE54ADE7E7C8CB3417C81603B080A8EEFC56072811129737CED96236B9364E22CE3A5 THEN 'PASS' ELSE 'FAIL INVALID RESULT' END
PRINT 'Duration (ms): ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(23),DATEDIFF(ms,@start,SYSDATETIME()))

*/

  DECLARE @NumDigestSizesRequiredToEncompassOutputbytes INT
  DECLARE @RemainderOutputbytesAfterNumDigestSizesMinusOne INT
  DECLARE @Working BINARY(64) -- digest size
  DECLARE @ThisIterationResult BINARY(64) -- digest size
  DECLARE @FirstIterationDefinedResult VARBINARY(4004) -- Salt size + INT size per HMAC definition
  DECLARE @output VARBINARY(8000)
  DECLARE @CurrentDigestSizeChunk INT
  DECLARE @CurrentIteration INT
  -- Start Inlined HMAC-SHA-512 variables
  DECLARE @ipadRFC2104 BIGINT
  DECLARE @opadRFC2104 BIGINT
  DECLARE @k_ipadRFC2104 BINARY(128) -- BLOCKSIZE in bytes per HMAC definition
  DECLARE @k_opadRFC2104 BINARY(128) -- BLOCKSIZE in bytes per HMAC definition
  --SQL fails to allow binary operations on two binary data types!!!  We use bigint and iterate 8 times for 512 bits = 64 byte blocksize for better performance.
  SET @ipadRFC2104 = CAST(0x3636363636363636 AS BIGINT)
  SET @opadRFC2104 = CAST(0x5C5C5C5C5C5C5C5C AS BIGINT)
  -- End Inlined HMAC-SHA-512 variables  

  SET @NumDigestSizesRequiredToEncompassOutputbytes = (@Outputbytes + 63)/64 -- number > 1 is digest size/digest size minus 1
  SET @RemainderOutputbytesAfterNumDigestSizesMinusOne = @Outputbytes - (@NumDigestSizesRequiredToEncompassOutputbytes - 1) * 64 -- the number in here that's > 1 is the digest size


  SET @output = 0x
  SET @CurrentDigestSizeChunk = 1

  WHILE @CurrentDigestSizeChunk <= @NumDigestSizesRequiredToEncompassOutputbytes
  BEGIN
    SET @FirstIterationDefinedResult = @Salt + CAST(@CurrentDigestSizeChunk AS VARBINARY(4))
    --SET @ThisIterationResult = YourDB.dbo.Yourfn_CRYPT_HMAC_SHA512(@Password,@FirstIterationDefinedResult)

    -- NOTE: Inlining HMAC-SHA-512 appears to improve performance by a factor of six or so.  Setting the HMAC as an Inlined Table Valued Function instead of a Scalar function would reduce this disparity, of course.
    -- START INLINED HMAC-SHA-512 for performance improvement
    -- B = BLOCKSIZE (64 bytes for MD5, SHA-224, SHA-256, and 128 bytes for SHA-384 and SHA-512, per RFC2104 and RFC4868)
    IF LEN(@Password) > 128 -- Applications that use keys longer than B bytes will first hash the key using H and then use the resultant L byte string as the actual key to HMAC 
      SET @Password = CAST(HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @Password) AS BINARY (128))
    ELSE
      SET @Password = CAST(@Password AS BINARY (128)) -- append zeros to the end of K to create a B byte string

    -- Loop unrolled for definite performance benefit
    -- Must XOR BLOCKSIZE bytes
    SET @k_ipadRFC2104 = CONVERT(BINARY(8),(SUBSTRING(@Password, 1, 8) ^ @ipadRFC2104))
      + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(SUBSTRING(@Password, 9, 8) ^ @ipadRFC2104))
      + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(SUBSTRING(@Password, 17, 8) ^ @ipadRFC2104))
      + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(SUBSTRING(@Password, 25, 8) ^ @ipadRFC2104))
      + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(SUBSTRING(@Password, 33, 8) ^ @ipadRFC2104))
      + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(SUBSTRING(@Password, 41, 8) ^ @ipadRFC2104))
      + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(SUBSTRING(@Password, 49, 8) ^ @ipadRFC2104))
      + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(SUBSTRING(@Password, 57, 8) ^ @ipadRFC2104))
      + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(SUBSTRING(@Password, 65, 8) ^ @ipadRFC2104))
      + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(SUBSTRING(@Password, 73, 8) ^ @ipadRFC2104))
      + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(SUBSTRING(@Password, 81, 8) ^ @ipadRFC2104))
      + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(SUBSTRING(@Password, 89, 8) ^ @ipadRFC2104))
      + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(SUBSTRING(@Password, 97, 8) ^ @ipadRFC2104))
      + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(SUBSTRING(@Password, 105, 8) ^ @ipadRFC2104))
      + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(SUBSTRING(@Password, 113, 8) ^ @ipadRFC2104))
      + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(SUBSTRING(@Password, 121, 8) ^ @ipadRFC2104))

    -- Loop unrolled for definite performance benefit
    -- Must XOR BLOCKSIZE bytes
    SET @k_opadRFC2104 = CONVERT(BINARY(8),(SUBSTRING(@Password, 1, 8) ^ @opadRFC2104))
      + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(SUBSTRING(@Password, 9, 8) ^ @opadRFC2104))
      + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(SUBSTRING(@Password, 17, 8) ^ @opadRFC2104))
      + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(SUBSTRING(@Password, 25, 8) ^ @opadRFC2104))
      + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(SUBSTRING(@Password, 33, 8) ^ @opadRFC2104))
      + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(SUBSTRING(@Password, 41, 8) ^ @opadRFC2104))
      + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(SUBSTRING(@Password, 49, 8) ^ @opadRFC2104))
      + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(SUBSTRING(@Password, 57, 8) ^ @opadRFC2104))
      + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(SUBSTRING(@Password, 65, 8) ^ @opadRFC2104))
      + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(SUBSTRING(@Password, 73, 8) ^ @opadRFC2104))
      + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(SUBSTRING(@Password, 81, 8) ^ @opadRFC2104))
      + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(SUBSTRING(@Password, 89, 8) ^ @opadRFC2104))
      + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(SUBSTRING(@Password, 97, 8) ^ @opadRFC2104))
      + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(SUBSTRING(@Password, 105, 8) ^ @opadRFC2104))
      + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(SUBSTRING(@Password, 113, 8) ^ @opadRFC2104))
      + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(SUBSTRING(@Password, 121, 8) ^ @opadRFC2104))

    SET @ThisIterationResult = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @k_opadRFC2104 + HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @k_ipadRFC2104 + @FirstIterationDefinedResult))
    -- END   INLINED HMAC-SHA-512 for performance improvement

    SET @Working = @ThisIterationResult

    SET @CurrentIteration = 1
    WHILE @CurrentIteration < @IterationCount
    BEGIN
      --SET @ThisIterationResult = YourDB.dbo.Yourfn_CRYPT_HMAC_SHA512(@Password,@ThisIterationResult)

      -- NOTE: Inlining HMAC-SHA-512 appears to improve performance by a factor of six or so.  Setting the HMAC as an Inlined Table Valued Function instead of a Scalar function would reduce this disparity, of course.
      -- START INLINED HMAC-SHA-512 for performance improvement
      -- B = BLOCKSIZE (64 bytes for MD5, SHA-224, SHA-256, and 128 bytes for SHA-384 and SHA-512, per RFC2104 and RFC4868)

      -- We've already hashed the password if we needed to!
      -- We've already generated @k_ipadRFC2104 and @k_opadRFC2104 both!

      SET @ThisIterationResult =  HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @k_opadRFC2104 + HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @k_ipadRFC2104 + @ThisIterationResult))
      -- END   INLINED HMAC-SHA-512 for performance improvement

      -- Loop unrolled for possible performance benefit
      -- Stupid conversion required because SQL Server can't do binary operations on two binary variables!!!
      -- Must XOR digest size bytes
      SET @Working = CONVERT(BINARY(8),(CONVERT(BIGINT,(SUBSTRING(@ThisIterationResult,1,8)))^SUBSTRING(@Working,1,8)))
        + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(CONVERT(BIGINT,(SUBSTRING(@ThisIterationResult,9,8)))^SUBSTRING(@Working,9,8)))
        + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(CONVERT(BIGINT,(SUBSTRING(@ThisIterationResult,17,8)))^SUBSTRING(@Working,17,8)))
        + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(CONVERT(BIGINT,(SUBSTRING(@ThisIterationResult,25,8)))^SUBSTRING(@Working,25,8)))
        + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(CONVERT(BIGINT,(SUBSTRING(@ThisIterationResult,33,8)))^SUBSTRING(@Working,33,8)))
        + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(CONVERT(BIGINT,(SUBSTRING(@ThisIterationResult,41,8)))^SUBSTRING(@Working,41,8)))
        + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(CONVERT(BIGINT,(SUBSTRING(@ThisIterationResult,49,8)))^SUBSTRING(@Working,49,8)))
        + CONVERT(BINARY(8),(CONVERT(BIGINT,(SUBSTRING(@ThisIterationResult,57,8)))^SUBSTRING(@Working,57,8)))

      SET @CurrentIteration += 1 -- SHA-512 is a SQL 2012 only function, so SQL 2008 only syntax doesn't limit compatibility any further.
    END -- WHILE @CurrentIteration rounds

    SELECT @output = @output +
      CASE
        WHEN @CurrentDigestSizeChunk = @NumDigestSizesRequiredToEncompassOutputbytes THEN CONVERT(BINARY(64),LEFT(@Working,@RemainderOutputbytesAfterNumDigestSizesMinusOne)) -- digest size in bytes
        ELSE CONVERT(BINARY(64),@Working) -- digest size in bytes
        END 
    SET @CurrentDigestSizeChunk += 1 -- SHA-512 is a SQL 2012 only function, so SQL 2008 only syntax doesn't limit compatibility any further.
  END

  RETURN @output

END


GO
```

Comment: If you must use SHA1 (i.e. SQL 2008 R2 and below), change all instances of digest size to 20 bytes, BLOCKSIZE to 64 bytes, LEN(@Password) check to 64 bytes (it's BLOCKSIZE as well), obviously change the HASHBYTES calls, cut the XOR unrolled loops down to a total of 64 bytes, and cut the @Working = ... XOR unrolled loop down to 20 bytes (i.e. two BIGINT and one INT).

Comment: SUBSTRING(@Password, 1, 8) ^ @ipadRFC2104 raises "Error converting data type varchar to bigint."

Comment: Version using SHA1, based on changes mentioned by @Anti-weakpasswords: https://gist.github.com/chaquotay/582c199a1fa135689800be7a5597e064

Comment: Note this is also at:  https://github.com/Anti-weakpasswords/PBKDF2-MSSQL-Custom-A

Answer (score 5):

Not that I know of, but I just wrote one for fun. I'm sure this can be optimized and tuned somewhat:

```
--Supporting HMAC function, based on http://www.experts-exchange.com/Microsoft/Development/MS-SQL-Server/SQL-Server-2005/Q_26290857.html
create FUNCTION [dbo].[test_HMAC]
(
        @hash_algorithm varchar(25),
        @key VARCHAR(MAX),
        @message VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)


AS
BEGIN
    --HASH key if longer than 16 characters
    IF(LEN(@key) >64)
        SET @key = HASHBYTES(@hash_algorithm,@key)


    DECLARE @i_key_pad VARCHAR(MAX), @o_key_pad VARCHAR(MAX), @position INT
        SET @position = 1
        SET @i_key_pad = ''
        SET @o_key_pad = ''

    --splice ipad & opod with key
    WHILE @position <= LEN(@key)
       BEGIN
        SET @i_key_pad = @i_key_pad + CHAR(ASCII(SUBSTRING(@key, @position, 1)) ^ 54) 
        SET @o_key_pad = @o_key_pad + CHAR(ASCII(SUBSTRING(@key, @position, 1)) ^ 92) 
        SET @position = @position + 1
       END 

    --pad i_key_pad & o_key_pad
        SET @i_key_pad = LEFT(@i_key_pad + REPLICATE('6',64),64)
        SET @o_key_pad = LEFT(@o_key_pad + REPLICATE('\',64),64)


RETURN HASHBYTES(@hash_algorithm,CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),@o_key_pad) + HASHBYTES(@hash_algorithm,@i_key_pad + @message))

END


--pbkdf2 in SQL
create function test_PBKDF2 
(
@hash_algorithm varchar(25),
@password varchar(max),
@salt varchar(max),
@rounds int,
@outputbytes int
)
returns varchar(max)
as
begin

declare @hlen int
select @hlen = len(HASHBYTES(@hash_algorithm, 'test'))
declare @l int = (@outputbytes +@hLen -1)/@hLen
declare @r int = @outputbytes - (@l - 1) * @hLen
declare @t varchar(max), @u varchar(max), @block1 varchar(max)

declare @output varchar(max) = ''

declare @i int = 1
while @i <= @l
    begin
    set @block1 = @salt +cast(cast(@i as varbinary(4)) as varchar(4))
    set @u = dbo.test_HMAC(@hash_algorithm,@password,@block1)
    set @t = @u

    declare @j int = 1
    while @j < @rounds
        begin
        set @u = dbo.test_HMAC(@hash_algorithm,@password,@u)


        declare @k int = 0, @workstring varchar(max) = ''
        while @k < @hLen
            begin
            set @workstring = @workstring + char(ascii(substring(@u,@k+1,1))^ascii(substring(@t,@k+1,1)))
            set @k+= 1
            end
        set @t = @workstring
        set @j+= 1
        end

        select @output = @output + case when @i = @l then left(@t,@r) else @t end
    set @i +=1
    end

return master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(convert(varbinary(max), @output ))

end
```

Usage Example from the RFC 6070 test vectors:

```
select dbo.test_PBKDF2('sha1', 'pass'+char(0)+'word', 'sa'+char(0)+'lt', 4096, 16) as hash
```

Comment: You should not answer just "for fun" and leaving the test for others. Your answers should be previously tested, at least you must be sure of providing a truly working code that answers OP question.

Comment: My code was tested and passes the test vectors specified in RFC 6070, as I show at the bottom. It was written primarily as an intellectual exercise rather than as part of an application being developed, i.e. "for fun".