# How to insert user records the database using the SQL query with hashing password like Asp.Net MVC hashing mechanism

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, hash

I have batch of user accounts and every user account's password is not crypted.I want to insert to user accounts to the database using `SQL Insert Query` but I want to hash the passwords while insert like `ASP.Net MVC` hashing mechanism in the query.

Is it possible , if it is how can I handle this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HASHBYTES` function for this. In my query i am hashing using MD5 algorithm.

```
INSERT INTO Userdetails_Tab(username,passwd,..,..)
values('test',HASHBYTES('MD5','testpass'),..,..)
```

Comment: But Microsoft.AspNet.Identity uses as hashing PBKDF2 (salt+hash).

Comment: look here for a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837547/is-there-a-sql-implementation-of-pbkdf2