# ASP.NET MVC Form encryption algorithm?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, encryption

What encryption algorithm is used in Form authentication when I use ASP.NET MVC 4?

The reason I'm asking is because I need to encrypt password on a phone and compare the hashed versions.

Answer (score 2):

[Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.aspx) doesn't handle validating a users password. Typically that is handled by the [MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx). Once you validate a users credentials, you can set an authentication cookie using Forms Authentication, which can then be validated by something like the [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

You can find the algorithm and format that the default membership provider uses to hash passwords in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137368/what-is-default-hash-algorithm-that-asp-net-membership-uses). You can also look at the implementation of [SimpleMembershipProvider](http://codefirstmembership.codeplex.com/), which has an example of generating correct membership hashes.

As a side note, if you're looking for something stronger than the default membership provider method, [StackOverflow](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/stack-exchange-is-an-openid-provider/#comment-59112) uses [PBKDF2](http://code.google.com/p/stackid/source/browse/OpenIdProvider/Current.cs#1135http://code.google.com/p/stackid/source/browse/OpenIdProvider/Current.cs#1135) to derive hashes, which slows down computation and makes brute force attacks harder.