# What is the hash logic in MVC 5 Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to MVC 5 Identity. I am trying to find what is the hash logic for password in mvc 5 identity.

I am trying to validate user outside .net project but using its table AspNetUsers. If I am correct in mvc 4 it was SHA1?? But I am not sure whats the same in MVC 5.

Also can we validate user in table AspNetUsers within the sql server using sql script itself?

Regards & Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is default hash algorithm that ASP.NET membership uses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137368/what-is-default-hash-algorithm-that-asp-net-membership-uses)

Comment: I am looking for mvc 5 identity. I think membership was for MVC4.

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/PasswordHasher.cs

> ### Version 2:
>
> PBKDF2 with HMAC-SHA1, 128-bit salt, 256-bit subkey, 1000 iterations.
>   (See also: SDL crypto guidelines v5.1, Part III)
>
> Format: { 0x00, salt, subkey }
>
> ### Version 3:
>
> PBKDF2 with HMAC-SHA256, 128-bit salt, 256-bit subkey, 10000 iterations.
>
> Format: { 0x01, prf (UInt32), iter count (UInt32), salt length (UInt32), salt, subkey }
>   (All UInt32s are stored big-endian.)

Comment: How do I update to version 3?  When I look at the Nuget Package Manager, I'm already on the latest version, 2.2.1 for the Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core package

Comment: Il s'agit de la version AspNet Core `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`