# How to store salted hashed password in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to figure out a way to store a salted hashed password to my database. It's my first time doing so, so I'm kind of unsure of how the process should go about.

My ASP.NET C# Web Application first requires a user to register for an account. I have a data layer, business layer to call the method in the data layer, and a presentation layer to display the form controls. At the moment I'm using plain text to store the password in the database. Let's call that method `createAccount()` in the data layer. Username, password and other attributes are passed into the `createAccount()` method to invoke the SQL Query to create an `Account` record. Username and password is specified by the user in the registration page. I found a web site that provided me a method to generate my password with hash as follow:

```
        public static string GenerateHashWithSalt(string password, string salt)
    {
        // merge password and salt together
        string sHashWithSalt = password + salt;
        // convert this merged value to a byte array
        byte[] saltedHashBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sHashWithSalt);
        // use hash algorithm to compute the hash
        System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm algorithm = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed();
        // convert merged bytes to a hash as byte array
        byte[] hash = algorithm.ComputeHash(saltedHashBytes);
        // return the has as a base 64 encoded string
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
    }
```

Where should I put this, in the registration page, in the code-behind (`.cs`) page, or in the data layer? And then, how would you all suggest I placed this hashed password in my database along with my other attributes? Should I directly store it as hashed, or store it in plaintext first, then update it to the hashed value. Thanks!

Comment: Store the salt as plain text and the hash as bytes or base64 encoded text. Do not store the password at all.

Comment: See https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm. In addition to @AndrewBarber's comment, also ensure you are hashing on the *server* - where you put the logic doesn't matter as much as you ensuring you don't do it client side.

Comment: Yes, I've managed to pass in my username as the salt, to the hashed password. I placed the code on both my data layer (to add to the database) and presentation layer (to compare login input's password). Thank you so much guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using an existing implementation, instead of rolling your own here.

The [asp.net membership](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) database is perfect for this, and [uses salting and hashing out of the box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137368/what-is-default-hash-algorithm-that-asp-net-membership-uses).