# Updating existing LocalDB entry with hashed password?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, hash, localdb

I'm developing a task (nothing professional, just for learning), where I have an application that has a web application in ASP.NET and an administrator application in WPF. Both of these projects connect to the same localdb database. The task is to make sure that only non-admins can register on the web app, but admins on the WPF app also need authentication (and the Users table also has some dependencies).

So, the database is like:

```
UsrName  UsrPwd   IsAdmin
admin    NULL     True
nonadmin kdjfgbjk False
```

My issue is, that the `UsrPwd` only contains the *hashed* passwords for the users bc of security reasons. Now. Since only the non-admins get to register on the web app, I don't know how I can add passwords to the admins because of the hashing - I added the admins via SQL queries (that's why their `UsrPwd` are `NULL`).

So my question is: How can I update the password for an administrator user so that I know what the password is (think of me as the system administrator providing the initial passwords), BUT only the hashed password gets saved in the database?

I thought about solving the issue by registering a user and changing the `IsAdmin` to `True` via SQL, but since there's some foreign key dependencies on the admin usernames, I'd rather not do that (I'd have to rebuild the database).

Is there any way I can add passwords to the admin users? I think the keyword here is some kind of code-first migration maybe (?) but I don't how to do that or if that's even the way to go.

Thank you!

**EDIT**

I'm not really using Identity nor OWIN or such thing, all I do is:

```
using (SHA512CryptoServiceProvider provider = new SHA512CryptoServiceProvider())
{
    passwordBytes = provider.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(user.UserPassword));
}

_entities.SoftwareUser.Add(new SoftwareUser
{
    UsrName = user.UserName,
    UsrPwd = passwordBytes,
    IsAdmin = false,
});
```

Where `SoftwareUser` is the entity generated based on the database.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Membership or Identity? Here's a link on how to reverse and recreate password hashing for membership

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137368/what-is-default-hash-algorithm-that-asp-net-membership-uses

Comment: Here's a post explaining how Identity works

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20621950/asp-net-identity-default-password-hasher-how-does-it-work-and-is-it-secure

Comment: @WithMetta I don't think I'm using either, I'm just manually hashing the passwords (updated the post with code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put this somewhere that runs upon your web application's start.

```
Func<string, byte[]> getPwHash = (pwStr) => {
    using (SHA512CryptoServiceProvider provider = new SHA512CryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        return provider.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pwStr));
    }            
};



var nullpwUsers = _entities.SoftwareUser.Where(user => user.UsrPwd == null);
foreach(var user in nullpwUsers) 
{
    user.UserPwd = getPwHash("DefaultPassword");
}
_entities.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Cool! Only problem is, my `SoftwareEntities : DbContext` doesn't seem to have a `.Where` function.

Comment: `DbSet<SoftwareUser> does not contain definition for 'Where' and no extendion method ... ` error pops up.

Comment: Oh scrap that, I was missing a `Linq` import. Thank you!