# Implement pbkdf2 in aspnet membership provider - Non-negative number required

Tags: vb.net, hash, asp.net-membership, pbkdf2, sqlmembershipprovider

I have a requirement to implement Pbkdf2 to secure a very old application that uses aspnet membership provider. I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137368/what-is-default-hash-algorithm-that-asp-net-membership-uses?answertab=modifieddesc#tab-top) answer which is recent and useful, but unable to follow what is inside MyRfc2898DeriveBytes class and it is giving me following issue.. (also I am a c# dev but for this project working in vb.net)
So the issue could be related to language conversion.

I am getting

> Non-negative number required. Parameter name: srcOffset

at the following

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(m_buffer, m_startIndex, password, 0, size)
```

the m_startIndex here somehow becomes -1

Here is my code in vb

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Namespace custom.hashing.keyderivation
Public Class PBKDF2Hash
    Inherits KeyedHashAlgorithm

    Private Const kHashBytes As Integer = 64
    Private _ms As System.IO.MemoryStream
    Public Property WorkFactor As Integer

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
        Me.WorkFactor = 128000
        Me.Key = New Byte(31) {}

        Using rngCsp = New RNGCryptoServiceProvider()
            rngCsp.GetBytes(Me.Key)
        End Using
    End Sub

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property HashSize As Integer
        Get
            Return kHashBytes * 8
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub HashCore(ByVal array As Byte(), ByVal ibStart As Integer, ByVal cbSize As Integer)
        If IsNothing(_ms) Then
            _ms = New MemoryStream()
        End If

        _ms.Write(array, ibStart, cbSize)

        '(CSharpImpl.__Assign(_ms, If(_ms, New System.IO.MemoryStream()))).Write(array, ibStart, cbSize)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Function HashFinal() As Byte()
        If Me.Key Is Nothing OrElse Me.Key.Length = 0 Then
            Throw New CryptographicException("Missing KeyedAlgorithm key")
        End If

        _ms.Flush()
        Dim arr = _ms.ToArray()
        _ms = Nothing

        Using hmac As HMACSHA512 = New HMACSHA512()
            Return New MyRfc2898DeriveBytes(arr, Me.Key, Me.WorkFactor, hmac).GetBytes(kHashBytes)
        End Using
    End Function

    Public Overrides Sub Initialize()
        _ms = Nothing
    End Sub


End Class
End Namespace


Imports System.Diagnostics.Contracts
Imports System.Security
Imports System.Security.Cryptography


Public Class MyRfc2898DeriveBytes
Inherits DeriveBytes

Private m_buffer As Byte()
Private m_salt As Byte()
Private m_hmac As HMAC
Private m_iterations As UInteger
Private m_block As UInteger
Private m_startIndex As Integer = 0
Private m_endIndex As Integer = 0
Private m_blockSize As Integer = 0

<SecuritySafeCritical>
Public Sub New(ByVal password As Byte(), ByVal salt As Byte(), ByVal iterations As Integer, ByVal hmac As HMAC)
    salt = salt
    IterationCount = iterations
    hmac.Key = password
    m_hmac = hmac

    m_blockSize = hmac.HashSize >> 3

    ''' 
    Initialize()
End Sub

Public Property IterationCount As Integer
    Get
        Return CInt(m_iterations)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        If value <= 0 Then Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value", "Error: Iteration count is zero or less")
        m_iterations = CUInt(value)
        Initialize()
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Salt As Byte()
    Get
        Return CType(m_salt.Clone(), Byte())
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Byte())
        If value Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("value")
        If value.Length < 8 Then Throw New ArgumentException("Error: Salt size is less than 8")
        m_salt = CType(value.Clone(), Byte())
        Initialize()
    End Set
End Property

Public Overrides Function GetBytes(ByVal cb As Integer) As Byte()
    If cb <= 0 Then
        Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("cb", "Error: Hash size is zero or less")
    End If

    Contract.Assert(m_blockSize > 0)
    Dim password As Byte() = New Byte(cb - 1) {}
    Dim offset As Integer = 0
    Dim size As Integer = m_endIndex - m_startIndex

    If size > 0 Then

        If cb >= size Then
            Buffer.BlockCopy(m_buffer, m_startIndex, password, 0, size)
            m_startIndex = m_endIndex = 0
            offset += size
        Else
            Buffer.BlockCopy(m_buffer, m_startIndex, password, 0, cb)
            m_startIndex += cb
            Return password
        End If
    End If

    Contract.Assert(m_startIndex = 0 AndAlso m_endIndex = 0, "Invalid start or end index in the internal buffer.")

    While offset < cb
        Dim T_block As Byte() = Func()
        Dim remainder As Integer = cb - offset

        If remainder > m_blockSize Then
            Buffer.BlockCopy(T_block, 0, password, offset, m_blockSize)
            offset += m_blockSize
        Else
            Buffer.BlockCopy(T_block, 0, password, offset, remainder)
            offset += remainder
            Buffer.BlockCopy(T_block, remainder, m_buffer, m_startIndex, m_blockSize - remainder)
            m_endIndex += (m_blockSize - remainder)
            Return password
        End If
    End While

    Return password
End Function

Public Overrides Sub Reset()
    Initialize()
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    MyBase.Dispose(disposing)

    If disposing Then

        If m_hmac IsNot Nothing Then
            m_hmac.Dispose()
        End If

        If m_buffer IsNot Nothing Then
            Array.Clear(m_buffer, 0, m_buffer.Length)
        End If

        If m_salt IsNot Nothing Then
            Array.Clear(m_salt, 0, m_salt.Length)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Initialize()
    If m_buffer IsNot Nothing Then Array.Clear(m_buffer, 0, m_buffer.Length)
    m_buffer = New Byte(m_blockSize - 1) {}
    m_block = 1
    m_startIndex = m_endIndex = 0
End Sub

Friend Shared Function GetBytesFromInt(ByVal i As UInteger) As Byte()

End Function

Private Function Func() As Byte()
    Dim INT_block As Byte() = GetBytesFromInt(m_block)
    m_hmac.TransformBlock(m_salt, 0, m_salt.Length, Nothing, 0)
    m_hmac.TransformBlock(INT_block, 0, INT_block.Length, Nothing, 0)
    m_hmac.TransformFinalBlock(New Byte(-1) {}, 0, 0)
    Dim temp As Byte() = m_hmac.Hash
    m_hmac.Initialize()
    Dim ret As Byte() = temp

    For i As Integer = 2 To m_iterations
        m_hmac.TransformBlock(temp, 0, temp.Length, Nothing, 0)
        m_hmac.TransformFinalBlock(New Byte(-1) {}, 0, 0)
        temp = m_hmac.Hash

        For j As Integer = 0 To m_blockSize - 1
            ret(j) = ret(j) Xor temp(j)
        Next

        m_hmac.Initialize()
    Next

    If m_block = UInteger.MaxValue Then
        Throw New InvalidOperationException("Derived key too long.")
    End If

    m_block += 1
    Return ret
End Function



End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yes it was c# to vb conversion issues:

1. double assignment does not work in vb, so the following line was changed from

   ```
   m_startIndex = m_endIndex = 0
   ```

to

```
 m_startIndex = 0
 m_endIndex = 0
```

2. Other things that I found

Property with same name as variable was not converted properly so

```
Public Sub New(ByVal password As Byte(), ByVal salt As Byte(), ByVal iterations As Integer, ByVal hmac As HMAC)
salt = salt
```

was really supposed to be

```
Public Sub New(ByVal password As Byte(), ByVal salt As Byte(), ByVal iterations As Integer, ByVal hmac As HMAC)
Me.Salt = salt
```

as Salt was a property

3. GetBytesFromInt(m_block) was not properly converted to vb

   ```
    Friend Shared Function GetBytesFromInt(ByVal i As UInteger) As Byte()
    Dim vIn As UInteger = 0
    Dim vOut As Byte() = BitConverter.GetBytes(i)
    Return vOut

    'return unchecked(new byte[] { (byte)(i >> 24), (byte)(i >> 16), (byte)(i >> 8), (byte)i });
   End Function
   ```